# Gridview image change from according to sharedPrefarance data position in android

Tags: android, gridview

I want to change the GridView Image change according to SharedPrefarance Data and position.
I have a LinkActivty. In this activity i have saved some data in sharedPrefarance according to gridview position

```
public class LinkActivity extends Activity {

TextView textView;
TextView textView2;

String[] text = { "robin", "robin", "pavel", "robin", "pavel", "robin",
        "pavel", "robin", "pavel", "robin", "pavel", "robin", };

private Button button;

public static final String[] Name = { "name", "pavel", "rimon", "robin",
        "class", "osdsd", "sadajhjkhsd", "sadd", "sakdods", "psadkds", "sajdka",
        "asdjkjsdk" };

public static final String[] list = { "na", "p", "r", "rs", "c", "o",
        "asdasd", "sadadsad", "paa", "ron", "reod", "rodela" };

private EditText editText;

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_link);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    final int link = bundle.getInt("link");
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView.setText(text[link]);

    if (sharedPreferences.contains(Name[link])) {

        textView2.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(Name[link], ""));
    }
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String name = editText.getText().toString();

            if (name.equals(text[link])) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Right", 200).show();

                name(Name[link], list[link]);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wrong", 200).show();
            }
        }

    });
}

public void name(String name, String tr) {
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(name, tr);
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

My CustomGrideView

```
public class CustomGridView extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private final int[] imageid;
private final String[] web;

private int[] clickImage;

public CustomGridView(Context context, int[] imageid, String[] web) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.imageid = imageid;
    this.web = web;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return web.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View grid;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        grid = new View(context);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid
                .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        //ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) grid
            //  .findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        textView.setText(web[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageid[position]);
        //imageView2.setImageResource(clickImage[position]);
    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }

    return grid;
}
```

}

In my MainActivity i want to change the gridview Image in that position which my sharedprefarance data will saved.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private GridView gridView;
int link;

String clickid;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

public String[] web = { "google", "google", "google", "google", "google",
        "google", "google", "google", "google", "google", "google",
        "google"

};

public static final String[] Name = { "name", "pavel", "rimon", "robin",
        "class", "osdsd", "sadajhjkhsd", "sadd", "sakdods", "psadkds",
        "sajdka", "asdjkjsdk" };

public static final String[] list = { "na", "p", "r", "rs", "c", "o",
        "asdasd", "sadadsad", "paa", "ron", "reod", "rodela" };

String[] text = { "robin", "robin", "pavel", "robin", "pavel", "robin",
        "pavel", "robin", "pavel", "robin", "pavel", "robin", };

int[] imageId = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, };

int[] signImage = { R.drawable.correct, R.drawable.correct,
        R.drawable.correct, R.drawable.correct, R.drawable.correct,
        R.drawable.correct, R.drawable.correct, R.drawable.correct,
        R.drawable.correct, R.drawable.correct, R.drawable.correct,
        R.drawable.correct };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CustomGridView adapterCustomGridView = new CustomGridView(
            MainActivity.this, imageId, web);
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    // for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

    // clickid = sharedPreferences.getString(Name[i], list[link]);
    // }

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapterCustomGridView);

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        String cliclString = sharedPreferences.getString(Name[i], list[i]);
        if (cliclString == text[i]) {
            adapterCustomGridView = new CustomGridView(MainActivity.this,
                    signImage, web);
        }
    }

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    LinkActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("link", position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

}

When i run my project it shows clickImage into all the gridview image.
I want to show click image in particular position in which position the data have saved.
I think the main problem in MainActivity sharedprefarance.I used some condition for sharedprefarnce i don't read and judge data perfectly.
How to do this.

Comment: Please add your code for CustomGridView.

Comment: yap add this @InnekeDeClippel

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use the View 'grid' in getView. Use convertView:

```
convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
```

This is all you should do in the in the if-statement there. So everything that follows, such as getting the textview and imageview, and adding text, do that outside of the if-statement. Remove the 'else'. Now I suppose you have 1 String and 1 image resource for every position. You don't have to call the constructor of your adapter every time in a for loop. Just do it once, with the correct String array and  int array. Your int array (with the resources) will have the same size as the String array. You can still use the for-loop in your Activity. Use it to populate a new int[]: the one you will pas to your adapter. If true, add an item of signImage, else add an item of imageId.